# I am having an issue sending an ID to the controller after a custom lookup on a Visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

I am trying to send an ID to a controller after a lookup on a Visualforce page.  The ID always comes in as null.  I have to mention that the lookup is going through a custom lookup javascript function that overrides the Salesforce lookup function. Based on that lookup ID I want to rerender parts of the page that involve that lookup.

Here is my lookup field and actionsupport that should send the Project__c

```
<apex:inputField id="ProjectLookup" tabOrderHint="1" value="{!solarDisclosure.Project__c}" required="true" html-read-only="true">
     <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!updateFieldsBasedOnProject}" rerender="SolarDisclosureFields" immediate="true"/>
</apex:inputField>
```

I have to put immediate true or else it doesn't seem to trigger the controller, maybe because I have validations.

this is my controller function...

````
    public PageReference updateFieldsBasedOnProject(){
        // Use the selectedProjectId variable to update the fields in the solarDisclosure object
        // selectedProjectId = solarDisclosure.Project__c;
        system.debug('solarDisclosure.Project__c: ' + solarDisclosure.Project__c);
        selectedProjectId = solarDisclosure.Project__c;
        system.debug('selectedProjectId: ' + selectedProjectId);
    
        // Assuming that the variable selectedProjectId contains the selected Project's ID
        Project__c selectedProject = [SELECT Id, Project_Location__c, Name FROM Project__c WHERE Id = :selectedProjectId];
        solarDisclosure.Project_Location__c = selectedProject.Project_Location__c;
        solarDisclosure.Project_Name__c = selectedProject.Name;
        return null;
    }```

I am always getting null for solarDisclosure.Project__c

I have tried to do this with vanilla javascript and sforce and seemed to get somewhere but would like to get this to work server side if I can.

I am trying to update the fields based on the lookup as seen here.
````

Answer (score 0):

On commandButtons `immediate=true` skips setters, getters and field-level validations (like `required=true`, it won't skip the real server-side validation rules for example). I suspect it's same for actionSupport's `immediate`. So for you the problem is the fact it doesn't set setters, values aren't passed.

You could try with passing the value you want via `apex:param` inside that actionSupport, bit like my ancient answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/4950/799

But I think for you more "natural", more visualforce way of doing things would be using `actionRegion` to submit just the part of the page where your field is, not the whole form. Try running the example from https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/22216/799